# Got failure in integration testing of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, byebug

I was developing sample project of Rails tutorial (M. Hartl) but at the end of chapter 9 I got failure for integration testing.

Assertion of test is like below:

```
assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
```

Body of error is:

```
FAIL["test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links", UsersIndexTest, 2016-01-25 23:03:39 +0330]
 test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links#UsersIndexTest (1453750419.70s)
        Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/users/157312430"]", found 0..
        Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

So used byebug for debugging of test but not found any problem with it. Response of server to test module is as here (Result of "**JSON.parse(response.body)**"):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>All users | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-22ded774de18638e5d5df16d8f71a98d1ef8dd1443b345f205c4312455504d14.css" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
  <script src="/assets/application-5f571eb3f10beb2509afac14df9da5d9dcd4afe9869ec7dcbc032ff50364d876.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <a id="logo" href="/">sample app</a>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="/users">Users</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/users/762146111">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="/users/762146111/edit">Settings</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log out</a> </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <h1>All users</h1>

<div class="pagination"><ul class="pagination"><li class="prev previous_page disabled"><a href="#">&#8592; Previous</a></li> <li class="active"><a rel="start" href="/users?page=1">1</a></li> <li><a rel="next" href="/users?page=2">2</a></li> <li class="next next_page "><a rel="next" href="/users?page=2">Next &#8594;</a></li></ul></div>

<ul class="users">
  <li>
  <img alt="User 19" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/9538140816b147f95b24b9cf9e052657?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/14035331">User 19</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/14035331">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 15" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/00ef7603e06e47d4a56d219f777b4f8c?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/157312430">User 15</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/157312430">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 7" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/77390d563208e0b52a1b5738ad5ab4ba?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/172816471">User 7</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/172816471">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 23" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/c362e2d6797a6296bb3f81e2aeb9d588?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/187601757">User 23</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/187601757">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 27" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/62506fe0a7f45e009116c1929ba91175?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/205739844">User 27</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/205739844">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 3" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/4c42f5c3c13f092769cb0a695acc3d63?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/220281934">User 3</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/220281934">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 11" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/637f1bf55f5d21863f52d5c4f1ac5c62?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/235774389">User 11</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/235774389">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 16" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/abe3d2fffb6bb035d84880dc2da9ad87?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/275330066">User 16</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/275330066">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 20" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/1b65d049a825d7f33e9e3250d6f773c3?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/304595689">User 20</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/304595689">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 4" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2462cf807167af6128cde02fc8f000f0?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/323332591">User 4</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/323332591">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 0" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/5f9770e6c24be5645e12384e284860bf?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/338193910">User 0</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/338193910">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 24" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/4595a63d7d99d2f332e58d967cbbe515?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/357172992">User 24</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/357172992">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 12" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/1aea9800a38f49f4339427ee1139806c?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/386199561">User 12</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/386199561">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="Lana Kane" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/de9a58df9617af487e8b28dbb3aa50de?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/409608538">Lana Kane</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/409608538">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 8" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/57326f96e0cf2fcdce1d6fcf4743e67d?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/452191684">User 8</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/452191684">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 28" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/decde8d24d5db7226cceaaa0a14bb2b9?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/486296279">User 28</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/486296279">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 13" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/fcc71816a3d5e6591a796fc4602019f7?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/537116830">User 13</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/537116830">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 25" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/de38a1dc7022b750c4dbf3914946565e?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/575485547">User 25</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/575485547">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 1" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/622eb90d6d19960af330457aecc562a1?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/590306657">User 1</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/590306657">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 5" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/a81486f15e54a5e7e02fcc9314578926?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/608344442">User 5</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/608344442">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 21" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/4fff217808f6fd90877428c222cded25?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/622916212">User 21</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/622916212">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 17" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d3907b7aa9d8573328daaffb87c276ad?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/661521543">User 17</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/661521543">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 29" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/1702ee830ca7e896da0cb29be3d1ed7c?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/737901126">User 29</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/737901126">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="Michael Example" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/03ea78c0884c9ac0f73e6af7b9649e90?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/762146111">Michael Example</a>

</li><li>
  <img alt="User 9" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e467a49a5c504bf70a082292cfdc622a?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/771020115">User 9</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/771020115">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="Mallory Archer" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2fcffc6793befd1fbc6121f441d34c01?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/785162917">Mallory Archer</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/785162917">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 18" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/593513ce88555bd017caf8a20f9ab042?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/936450328">User 18</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/936450328">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="Sterling Archer" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d08d4b6a8f375370ad3b1423dca85da8?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/950961012">Sterling Archer</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/950961012">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 10" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/9f1511aadf13b07a63073efb3cf80e7a?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/956993830">User 10</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/956993830">delete</a>
</li><li>
  <img alt="User 2" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/cdd723a3c6b4599704b8ed02339b2e80?s=50" />
  <a href="/users/975572189">User 2</a>

      | <a data-confirm="You Sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/975572189">delete</a>
</li>
</ul>

<div class="pagination"><ul class="pagination"><li class="prev previous_page disabled"><a href="#">&#8592; Previous</a></li> <li class="active"><a rel="start" href="/users?page=1">1</a></li> <li><a rel="next" href="/users?page=2">2</a></li> <li class="next next_page "><a rel="next" href="/users?page=2">Next &#8594;</a></li></ul></div>
  <footer class="footer">
  <small>
    The <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    by <a href="http://www.michaelhartl.com/">Michael Hartl</a>
  </small>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://news.railstutorial.org/">News</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Response of watching "**p user**" is:

```
#<User id: 14035331, name: "User 19", email: "user-19@example.com", created_at: "2016-01-26 04:13:50", updated_at: "2016-01-26 04:13:50", password_digest: "$2a$04$dTwCZcN7xWivGrZvlJrpzuBNZDaOKd4paCesVp8tK0k...", remember_digest: nil, admin: false>
```

**Update:**

Integration test is:

```
  test "index as admin including pagination and delete links" do
    log_in_as(@admin)
    get users_path
    assert_template 'users/index'
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
    first_page_of_users.each do |user|
      byebug
      assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
      unless user == @admin
        assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete',
          method: :delete
      end
      assert_difference 'User.count', -1 do
        delete user_path(@non_admin)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: the problem can be in test itself. Please, add your test to your question.

Comment: What? Why are you calling `JSON.parse(response.body)` on a HTML response? And even more important - why is the response JSON encoded?

Comment: @max: I used these functions for debugging (checking out response with test)

Comment: @TetianaChupryna: I updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tetiana Chupryna said, I revised my test's source and found out problem was iterating users to following part of code (wrong placement of end).

Updated version of test which works fine:

```
  test "index as admin including pagination and delete links" do
    log_in_as(@admin)
    get users_path
    assert_template 'users/index'
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
    first_page_of_users.each do |user|
      assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
      unless user == @admin
        assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete',
          method: :delete
      end
    end

    assert_difference 'User.count', -1 do
      delete user_path(@non_admin)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Note that running assertions in a loop is generally regarded as a poor practice. Its an open invitation for false positives. Instead sample the first and last and write assertions on them.

Comment: @max: This code is from Book of Rails Tutorial (https://www.railstutorial.org).
But I'm completely agree with you and best practice is checking some field not all.
Thanks to your advice

Comment: Ah, yeah don't know why he let the quality drop so much when he switched to minitest.