# Hartl Sample App Failure in integration test for assert_select a[href=?]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been working through the Hartl sample app course, and while I have had issues here and there, I have always been able to find answers, or identify the kink in my code by comparing with the tutorial git. However this time I am at a loss and am hoping someone in the community can figure out where I may have gone wrong.

I am getting the following minitest error:

```
    Minitest::Assertion: Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/users/14035331"]", found 0..
    Expected 0 to be >= 1.
    test/integration/users_index_test.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
    test/integration/users_index_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
```

Here is the code for the test which is exactly as it appears in the tutorial:

```
    require 'test_helper'

    class UsersIndexTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

      def setup
       @user = users(:james)
      end

      test "index including pagination" do
        log_in_as(@user)
        get users_path
        assert_template 'users/index'
        assert_select 'div.pagination'
        User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
           assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
        end
      end
    end
```

User 14035331 is the ID of the first record in the test.db. Possible issues I can think of but haven't been successful in identifying - User is not on Page 1 (this shouldn't be since it is the first ID record); the test is looking for the NAME field but getting the ID field.

I did find a similar question on here, but it doesn't address this problem. You can see the thread here: [Got failure in integration testing of rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007124/got-failure-in-integration-testing-of-rails)

That user is a bit further along, and I really hate to refractor and push forward when my test suite isn't passing.

Comment: How many users are in your database and in what order do you have them showing up?

Comment: There are 34 users, paginate at 30. I *thought they were listed numerically by ID which puts the error user as #1 in the DB.

Comment: Do you have them ordered in any way?

Comment: Hashrocket - I do not see an order defined. Would it not default to ID?

Comment: `<% 30.times do |n| %>
user_<%= n %>:
  name: <%= "User #{n}" %>
  email: <%= "user-#{n}@example.com" %>
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
<% end %>`

Comment: I’m just thinking that maybe your users are getting ordered in descending order, so the user with id 1 is actually at the bottom of the pagination, not at the top.

Comment: Its a reasonable assumption. Fits with my #1 reason. How do I force order by ID?  something like: User.order('id ASC')

Comment: Why don’t you try to have your test paginate at page 2 and then see if the user shows up?

Comment: Ok I think you are on to something. I changed to page: 2 and got the same error but with the highest ID #:

Comment: Minitest::Assertion: Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/users/994338771"]", found 0..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to HASHROCKET I was able to determine that somehow my DB was sorted by ID DESC and my test expected it to be ASC. I am not sure how that happened exactly but I added the following line to the end of users.yml to force order by ID ASC and the test is green.

```
    <% User.order(id: :asc) %>
```